# Omitting Subject Relative Pronouns

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Most textbooks state that subject relative pronouns cannot be omitted, e.g.

> A: Alan threatened Brian.
>
> B: Alan was a gangster.
>
> A+B = Alan, who was a gangster, threatened Brian.

However, sometimes I will see the following:

> A+B = Alan, a gangster, threatened Brian.

Is this standard usage? If so, is it still a relative clause or something else entirely?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second example, *a ganster* is an [appositive](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/appositives/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an appositive, a noun or noun phrase immediately following another noun that renames or identifies that other noun.

Comment: Sorry, I know I shouldn't use a comment to say thank you, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!